# How to make my bot respond to someone after an initial response?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot command so when you type `,num-guess` the bot says `'[username] guess a number between 1 and 10, you have 3 guesses.'`
which works but it also says `'[username] you have not correctly guessed it, you have 3 guesses left'` 3 times right after. Instead, I want it so when you guess it wrong it says `'[username] you have not correctly guessed it, you have 2 guesses left,'` then 1 guesses left, then 1 more wrong guesses it would say `'Sorry [username] you did not guesses they number'`, but it does not work

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'num-guess',
    description: 'User has to guess a number between 1 - 10',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        NumberToChoose = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        const Number = NumberToChoose[Math.floor(Math.random() * NumberToChoose.length)];
        message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} guess a number from 1 - 10`);

        var MaxGuess = 3
        var CorrectAnswer = Number
        var GuessesLeft = MaxGuess
        var Guess = message.author.message

        for (i=0; i<MaxGuess; i++){
            if(CorrectAnswer == Guess){
                message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} you have guessed the number correctly`);
                break;
            }
            else {
                var GuessesLeft = GuessesLeft--
                message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} you have not correctly guessed it, you have ${GuessesLeft} left`)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the bot says:

```
[username] guess a number from 1 - 10
[username] you have not correctly guessed it, you have 3 left
[username] you have not correctly guessed it, you have 3 left
[username] you have not correctly guessed it, you have 3 left
```

What I want it to say:

```
[username] guess a number from 1 -10
[user]: 1
(if correct number) [username] you have guessed the number correctly
(if not the correct number) [username] you have not correctly guessed the number, you have [number of more tries] left
(repeat until lose or win)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [postfix decrement operator (`n--`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) has a bit of a confusing feature that makes it more confusing than just using the [subtraction assignment operator (`n -= x`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction_assignment). When using this operator, it will increment the variable, but return the original value. Here's an example:

```js
let number = 1;
const increment = number--;

// number was decremented correctly and is now zero
console.log(`Number: ${number}`);

// but increment takes the value of the original number
console.log(`Increment: ${increment}`);
```

Since you're assigning `n--` to a variable and using that, the number isn't actually going to change, since it's using the original value each time. There are many ways to prevent this:

- The easiest way by far would just be not to reassign `GuessesLeft` to another variable by the same name. This operator will edit values in place, so there's no need to do anything but use the operator.

```js
// original: 
// var GuessesLeft = GuessesLeft--

GuessesLeft--
```

- Use the *pre*fix decrement operator (`--n`). It does the same thing, but this time actually returns the modified number.
- Use the subtraction assignment operator. `GuessesLeft -= 1`. It might not be as short and sweet, but it's much easier to understand, and none of the confusing "post"/"pre" curveballs come into effect.

---

Also, I'm pretty sure that you'll never be able to guess the number correctly.  `message.author.message` is not a thing, so `Guess` will be undefined, and it doesn't look like it's actually prompting you for further answers.

Comment: that fixed the subtraction thing, but aint fixing the repeating thing

Comment: Did you see the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: yeah but how do i fix it? so the bot only responds when a user answers

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector

Comment: can u send a video of somesorts because i haven't read in a long time, so this hurts my brian

Comment: Just look up "discord.js message collectors" on youtube or something